# Installing programs via wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

Which is better to install windows programs, with wine itself (wine program.exe) or via PlayOnLinux?

Comment: Both have their benefits and drawbacks, so it depends on your specific needs.

Comment: can you tell me about those benefits and drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

PlayOnLinux is a frontend for Wine and simply makes it easier to manage Wine prefixes and dependencies.

You can install Wine by itself, or use PlayOnLinux as a manager. PlayOnLinux can also make it easier to pick specific Wine distributions and games.

Comment: so via PlayOnLinux is easier, isn't it?

Comment: @Steve For people who wish for an easy way to manage different prefixes and applications, yes, PlayOnLinux is an easier way to Wine.